# FIrst EntityDataSource Works, Second Says Connection For First is Empty or Invalid

Tags: .net, entity-framework, connection-string

I have been doing .NET for years but the Entity Model is eating my lunch.

I have been engaged for my school in adapting exercises from the `70-515 Training Kit` to be used on `Visual Studio 2013` while we write new courses. I have been unable to get the exercise on pages `716-718` of the `Training Kit to work in Visual Studio 2013`.

I have been able to overcome assembly loading issues by changing my application pools to use 32-bit apps and have figured out how to get EF installed so the sources can be created. There are some problems with this (e.g. the EF is not creating the namespace) but the Entity Models are getting accepted.

The one error I have not been able to overcome is that the program errors out when the site is run saying this:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid.

I am using `Visual Studio 2013 Express` on `Windows 8.1`. Is there a versioning issue here?

What is weird here is that there are two `EntityDataSources` on the page - and the first one works. Both are using the same connection (I installed `LocalDB`). I have concluded that help is needed with this. Is there anyone out there who knows how to get this to work?

If the question is too long, can you give me the name of someone in the `Dallas-Fort Worth` area I can meet with on this?

> Note: This site does not like XML.  I will mail anyone who responds my
>   XML for the web.config and the Entity Model as attachments.

The markup on my page is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Customers</h2>
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=NorthwindEntitiesCnn" 
            DefaultContainerName="NorthwindEntitiesCnn" EnableFlattening="False" AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true"
            OrderBy="it.CompanyName" EntitySetName="Customers" 
            Select="it.[CompanyName], it.[CustomerID], it.[City], it.[Region], it.[Country], it.[Phone]">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCustomers" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Region" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CustomerID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="orders.aspx?custId={0}"
                    HeaderText="Orders" Text="view orders" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceCust" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=NorthwindEntitiesCnn" DefaultContainerName="NorthwindEntitiesCnn" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Customers" Where="it.CustomerID=@custId" Include="Orders">
          <WhereParameters>
              <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="custId" Name="custId" DbType="String"/>
          </WhereParameters>
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewCust" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceCust" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnDataBound="DetailsViewCust_DataBound">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" SortExpression="ContactName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactTitle" HeaderText="ContactTitle" SortExpression="ContactTitle" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" SortExpression="Region" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" SortExpression="PostalCode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewOrders" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
```

The codebehind for the page is as follows:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  protected void DetailsViewCust_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Customer cust =
    (Customer)DetailsViewCust.DataItem;
    this.GridViewOrders.DataSource = cust.Orders;
    this.GridViewOrders.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the connection strings from your web.config or app.config? It is a chance that something is wrong with them,

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb! I am sorry for wasting your time; in analyzing all the bizarre errors I got, after they were solved, I neglected to realize that the two entity data sources must be on separate pages! Sorry for wasting your bandwidth... if nothing else, putting my question down for you at least permitted me to organize my thoughts.

```
                                                        Clark.
```